# MacOS 10.13 High Sierra "pip3 install" command doesn't work (SSLError)

Tags: python, macos, pip, openssl

for my job purposes, I need a MacOS, but there is no possibility to use a real mac. So I decided to set up virtual machine, using Virtualbox. After the machine was successfully setup, I've opened the Terminal app and run the following commands:

1)`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"` (Homebrew install)
2)`brew install python` (Python 3 install)
3)`pip3 install numpy`

As an output of the last command, I got the next error message:

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy

    Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Of course, I've tried to find a solution online. Reinstalling python or openssl via Homebrew didn't help. Linking openssl or installing other CA also didn't solve the problem. How can I actually fix this?

P.C. I also know that Apple is a sh*t company and tries to have minimum hardware and software of other companies. That's why they use LibreSSL instead of OpenSSL. But the last one is one that Python requests in order to have the ability to install packages via pip. After python was installed, the following message was in terminal:

```
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.
If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH run:
 echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Running proposed command also doesn't solve the problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do `pip3 -V` and, for that matter, `python3 -m pip -V` yield?

Comment: @hoefling the output of both commands is:
```pip 20.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)```

Comment: Can you please also check whether the `ssl` module is available? `python3 -c "import ssl, _ssl; print(ssl.__file__); print(_ssl.__file__)"`

Comment: @hoefling, suddenly, it's not available :( Running ```python3 -c "import ssl"``` command caused the next **ImportError**:
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib```

Comment: This looks like an issue with your previous brewed installation of Python - why does `ssl` module point to a 3.7.4 installation when you have a 3.8? Maybe do a Homebrew reinstall from scratch, with a complete removal of `/usr/local/Cellar` (you can backup the list of installed packages via `brew ls > somefile`).

Comment: @hoefling, sorry about python 3.7.4 - I've just copied the same error text from internet because VM works very slow and it will take a lot of time to copy output, login and respond here. In my case, Python version was 3.8

Comment: @hoefling The output of my Mac console is:
```>>> import ssl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found```